# Resizing images and JPanel on JFrame when JFrame get resized

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have made a jframe which contain three jpanel ,these three panel devides the jframe into
three equal parts. each panel contain an image.I want to resize the images and panel when
frame get resizes from heigher to lower size.Can anybody tell how can i do it please.

Comment: Could you put some code? What have you tried?

Comment: The solution is to use the correct LayoutManager on the JFrame's content pane. For example, a GridLayout or a BorderLayout will automatically adapt to the frame size and will automatically increase the size of the content of the content pane

Answer (score 3):

Put image as:

1. [Icon / ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
2. you can use [paintComponent for JComponent or JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) with `getWidth` and `getHeight` instead of fixed size in pixels
3. instead of thinking about resize, use proper `LayoutManager` for placing `JPanels` or `JLabels` with image to the `JFrame`, e.g. `GridLayout` could be the easiest of the ways.

Comment: LOL that is sad.  **I** need to learn English one of these days.  ;)

Comment: my actual problem is of the size of image. when the image size is greater than the size of the frame it is not showing the full image.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem a few years back. Was just looking for the code but I couldn't find it.

Essentially, the answer is you use a ComponentListener to see when your Frame (or probably better, put one on each of your panels) has changed size. Then you can resize the image appropriately. I did this with BufferedImages. Using regular Image you need to create a new Image and draw the old image on the new one, but scaled. (use image.getGraphics and [`Graphics.drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29))

Comment: Someone downvoted, but [drawImage(..., width, height, ...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) scales the image. So the answer is in general correct. Call it in the `paintComponent`.

Comment: A `ComponentListener` is unnecessary for this.  You can simply redraw the scaled image whenever asked (when `paintCompoent()` is called).